# N-mosfet detects the proximity of my hand. Can it be useful?

Tags: mosfet

When the gate of an N-channel MOSFET is not connected, it allows current to pass from drain to source, and the amount of current depends on the distance between my hand (or a piece of metal touching my hand) and the MOSFET (or a wire connected to the gate). Are there any designs that take advantage of this?

Comment: No, not good ones. Use a theremin.

Comment: Highly unreliable proximity sensor?

Comment: This is a very dangerous situation...if you accidentally get close enough to the gate to discharge some static electricity you may destroy the MOSFET.

Comment: How do you think a touch-lamp works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  If you google "floating gate sensor" you will see there are many many applications for this effect.

[Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-gate_MOSFET).

From [sensing radiation](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6377101/), to [measuring fatigue in steel plates](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0141029617303498), there are lots of ways to use this effect.  EPROM, EEPROM, and flash all use this effect as well.